# how to find sum of elements in a list that satisfy sum(L)=k where L is a list and k is positive integer?

Tags: python

Given list L or sub-list of L and k positive integer as input, I need to define a recursive function (without using slicing) that its input is (L,k) and returns True if sum(L)=k and False if not.

I tried the following code:

```
def sum_rec(L,k):
   import itertools
   n = len(L)
   i=0
   if sum(L) == k:
        return True
   while len(L)> 1:
       sub_L = list(itertools.combinations(L, n-i-1))
       i+=1
       for sub_lst in sub_L:
           s_rec(sub_lst,k)
   else:
       return False
```

I'm getting "ValueError: r must be non-negative", also the the code didn't check all the sub-lists. Is there any other way to do it? I'm using python 3.6.

Comment: Explain what part of you code doesn't work. What results are you getting that are wrong, and what results do you expect?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I can see an obvious error in your code, but it helps a lot if you can explain in more detail "didn't work well for me". you should post the error and traceback you're getting.

Comment: thanks, I just modified my post:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you the following solution, summing the element of each sub-list one by one by recursion (from the index 0), until the last element is reached:

```
from itertools import combinations

def AllSublists(L):
    """ Return list of sub-lists (of any size) from list L """
    return [list(j) for i in range(1, len(L)+1) for j in list(combinations(L, i))]

def RecIfSum(L, k, i=0):
    """ --------------- Recursive function -------------------
        Return True if sum(L) equals k, otherwise return False """
    if (i == len(L)-1):
        return (L[i] == k)
    else:
        L[i+1] += L[i]
        return RecIfSum(L, k, i+1)

def CheckIfSum(myList, k):
    """ Return True if the sum of a sub-list of myList equals k, otherwise return False """
    for L in AllSublists(myList):
        if RecIfSum(L, k):
            return True
    return False

print(CheckIfSum([1,4,8,9], 18)) # True
print(CheckIfSum([1,4,8,9], 19)) # False
print(CheckIfSum([1,4,8,9], 20)) # False
print(CheckIfSum([1,4,8,9], 21)) # True
print(CheckIfSum([1,4,8,9], 22)) # True
```

Comment: She mentioned in the question that we can't use slicing syntax.

Comment: @Shubham Oups I missed that. Thanks, I updated my answer to avoid using slicing.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but if you try recIfSum([1,4,8,9], 18) it returns false, even though  [1,4,8,9] contains sub-list that satisfy 8+9+1 = 18. sorry I didn't mention that in the question.

Comment: @romanasa OK, I missed that in your original request (I still do not find it very clear), but now I have understood. I updated my answer regarding your comment.

Comment: @Laurent H. Works like a charm, thank you for the help :)